# Oracle SQL -- can't insert into row

Tags: sql, oracle, privileges, tablespace

I have a newly created table. When I try to insert into it, I get..

```
SQL Error: ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'ADMINISTRATOR'
01950. 00000 -  "no privileges on tablespace '%s'"
*Cause:    User does not have privileges to allocate an extent in the
           specified tablespace.
*Action:   Grant the user the appropriate system privileges or grant the user
           space resource on the tablespace.
```

To fix this, I tried several things...

```
GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO MY_TABLE;


grant RESOURCE,CONNECT,UNLIMITED TABLESPACE to USER_NAME;


alter user "USER_NAME"  
quota unlimited on "ADMINISTRATOR"
```

...but the error remains. What is the cause of this failure and how can I fix it?

Comment: probably you should be building tables in the USERS tablespace...

Comment: That's solvable, but we'll need some diagnostics to help: Who owns the table, what's the default tablespace of that user. Is the table global temporary? Is it deferred segment creation? Who tries to insert?

Comment: Did you try GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO USER_NAME; Did you get an error or was it successful?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

alter database datafile '/u01/app/oracle/your_tablespace_datafile_name.dbf' autoextend on maxsize unlimited;

Comment: This is not a space issue. Did you see: "*no **privileges** on tablespace 'ADMINISTRATOR'*"